# How to join string and number suffixes together in Android/Java?

Tags: java, android

Well, I need to split a string, number, and the other string in order to get results with suffixes. I have this example string:

> **Recharge Data 100000 only in your location**

I was able to get this Log from the string above with this function in Java:

> **E/numberMatches: numberMatches: 10000**
>
> **E/formattedString: formattedString: 10k**

Here is the code of convert to suffixes string function:

```js
// code in GeneralUtils.java file

public static String extractNumber(final String str) {
  if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) return "";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  boolean found = false;
  for (char c: str.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
      sb.append(c);
      found = true;
    } else if (found) {
      break;
    }
  }
  return sb.toString();
}

private static final NavigableMap < Long, String > thousandSuffixes = new TreeMap < > ();

static {
  thousandSuffixes.put(1 _000L, "k");
  thousandSuffixes.put(1 _000_000L, "M");
  thousandSuffixes.put(1 _000_000_000L, "G");
  thousandSuffixes.put(1 _000_000_000_000L, "T");
  thousandSuffixes.put(1 _000_000_000_000_000L, "P");
  thousandSuffixes.put(1 _000_000_000_000_000_000L, "E");
}

public static String formatSuffixes(long value) {
  if (value == Long.MIN_VALUE) return formatSuffixes(Long.MIN_VALUE + 1);
  if (value < 0) return "-" + formatSuffixes(-value);
  if (value < 1000) return Long.toString(value);
  Map.Entry < Long, String > e = thousandSuffixes.floorEntry(value);
  Long divideBy = e.getKey();
  String suffix = e.getValue();
  long truncated = value / (divideBy / 10);
  boolean hasDecimal = truncated < 100 && (truncated / 10 d) != (truncated / 10);
  return hasDecimal ? (truncated / 10 d) + suffix : (truncated / 10) + suffix;
}
```

and here's the code to get the result from those function above:

```js
String product = productCategory.getProductName();
String number = GeneralUtils.extractNumber(product);
String formattedString = GeneralUtils.formatSuffixes(Long.valueOf(number));
Log.e("numberMatches", "numberMatches: " + number);
Log.e("formattedString", "formattedString: " + formattedString);
```

How do I join the formatted string with the string before and its after to get a result look like this in Android?

> **Recharge Data 100K only in your location**

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: `product.replaceAll("\\b" + number + "\\b", formattedString)`?

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for your reply, but what if the string contains number and string more than 2 times? like for example: **Regular Recharge 100000 only 95000 for today** , it needs to be converted to **Regular Recharge 100k only 95k for today**.

Comment: Then do it for both.

Comment: @AndyTurner is there any workaround to make a dynamic function that will detect if any thousands number in the string, it will convert to suffixes?

Comment: @AndyTurner Hi, your code works! Silly me I didn't realize that I have to create a new variable for **product.replaceAll("\\b" + number + "\\b", formattedString)** to work. Putting your first comment into an answer will be a good idea so I can accept it as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.replaceAll` to replace occurrences of `number` with `formattedString`:

```
String newProduct = product.replaceAll("\\b" + number + "\\b", formattedString);
```

Note that `number` should be surrounded by work breaks (as shown here) to ensure you don't accidentally replace, say, the `1000` and the start of `1000000` and get `1k000`.

You can do multiple replacements in a string using a `Matcher`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");  // Do this once, store in a constant.

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(product);
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
  String number = m.group();
  String formattedString = GeneralUtils.formatSuffixes(Long.valueOf(number));

  m.appendReplacement(sb, formattedString);
}
m.appendTail(sb);

String newProduct = sb.toString();
```